# Open Safari to the last tab that was opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

Is it possible to open Safari from code that will reopen Safari with the last tab open? I've searched around and I can only find how to open Safari with a URL (not what I want) or open it to a blank page (also not what I want). Is it possible to reopen Safari in its last state?

e.g. someone is on Google on Safari. They then hide the app and launch my app. I'd like my app to open Safari and show Google - I don't want to use the delegate bundle passed in during activation as the website may be expired or dynamic and so I don't want to reload the page.

Thanks